# Open Facebook and Instagram apps through an email link

Tags: android, ios, facebook, email, deep-linking

I want to send an email with a link to a webpage that will redirect to Facebook or Instagram. If the user is on a phone, I need the respective app to open. This needs to work on both iPhones and Android phones as well as simply open the web page if the user is on a desktop (and as a fallback).

As an example, I tried using `<a href="fb://profile">Facebook Profile</a>`, which worked on my android from a phone, but doesn't cover all my needs.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to use such custom protocol handlers, you’d first of all need to figure out a way to find out which of those the client supports – and from within the context of an email, I doubt that’s possible. Perhaps App Links can help you achieve what you want – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks, http://applinks.org/

Answer (score -1):

That is work in Facebook Page, also Instragram app will work.I hope it will be OK for You.Note : Please install and test Facebook Latest version app

```
 btnfFB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String url = "fb://page/yourpageID";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```